# How to most efficiently check for certain "breakpoints" upon browser re-size?

Tags: jquery, performance, window-resize

I'm playing with some responsive design that have two breakpoints defined:

```
Mobile > max-width 320px
Tablet portrait > max-width 767px
```

On desktop I have a lot of animation + advanced functionality going on with Javascript. On mobile and tablet im looking to simplify and disable both some JS + "re-building" some DOM elements.

**Im wondering what the most efficient way to determine certain breakpoints (in terms of width) would be? Im thinking a lot about performance here.**

I know I can simply check for the window width upon re-size with something like:

```
$( window ).resize(function() {
  if ($(window).width() > 320 && $(window).width() < 400) {
    //mobile
  }
  if ($(window).width() > 401 && $(window).width() < 768) {
    //tablet
  }
  if ($(window).width() > 769) {
    //desktop
  }
});
```

But that seems like a very "expensive" operation?

Any suggestions to lightweight libraries that can be used for this is also very welcome!

Comment: This may not help, which is why I'm leaving this as a comment instead, but a lot of times if you're looking for efficient ways to change layout and rebuild DOM elements, CSS is certainly a good friend. Your question is a little vague though, so it's hard to say.

Comment: Hi Michael - CSS will surely help me along way to go, but it's sadly not sufficient for all cases - especially if I want to disable certain parts of JS

Comment: Check out the other answers, but at the very least I'd change your ifs into an if/else if block. Aso, as written, there is no case that matches when the window width is exactly 400, 401, 768, or 769 pixels.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I often ran into this problem and have not found the perfect solution. However, there is a workaround that seems less resource hungry. By using a timeout inside your `resize()` function and constantly clearing it, you can make sure that your code is only run, once the viewport has stopped resizing.

```
var resizeTimer, width;
var mobile = tablet = desktop = false;

$(window).resize(function() {
    // clear the timeout
    clearTimeout(resizeTimer);

    // execute breakpointChange() once the viewport 
    // has stopped changing in size for 400ms
    resizeTimer = setTimeout(breakpointChange(), 400);
});

function breakpointChange() {
    // use vanillajs window.innerWidth 
    // instead of jQuery $(window).width() as suggested by simon
    width = window.innerWidth;

    if (!mobile && width < 400) {
        tablet = desktop = false;
        mobile = true;
        console.log('is mobile');
    }

    if (!tablet && width > 401 && width < 768) {
        mobile = desktop = false;
        tablet = true;
        console.log('is tablet');
    }

    if (!desktop && width > 769) {
        mobile = tablet = false;
        desktop = true;
        console.log('is desktop');
    }
}
$(window).resize();
```

This is certainly not the best one can do, but it will prevent that your code is *constantly* being run. Feel free to add to my answer and/or correct me. Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/70x736mf/2/)

Comment: Hi The F - I did actually think of some timer approach, the only thing that made it appeal a bit less interesting was just the delay it could create when actually requesting the solution for instance on mobile - then there would first be a delay in actually recognizing that we're on mobile and then afterwards the delay of whatever I want to trigger being on mobile.

But it could surely end up being the way for me to go, ill try and check out your example, cheers!

Comment: Hi, 400ms might actually be a little generous. Try decreasing it to 200ms and the delay should be almost unnoticable. I have updated the answer to be a bit more complete.

Answer (score 0):

It would be very performant when you stop using jQuery in cases where it is obsolete. JavaScript `window` object has `innerWidth` / `outerWidth` property which you can use without jQuery calls.

```
$( window ).resize(function() {
  var width = window.innerWidth; // e.g.

  if (width > 320 && width < 400) {
    //mobile
  }
});
```

So you don't have any performance issues because this is going to be just a property of an object and no function calls / coercions. If you do need here to know the device only this would be the perfect solution.

When you operate with DOM inside - look for timeouts as proposed by "The F"

Answer (score 0):

Use `window.matchMedia()`:

```js
const mobileQuery = window.matchMedia("(max-width: 320px)");
const tabletQuery = window.matchMedia("(max-width: 767px)");

function handleBreakpoints() {
    if (mobileQuery.matches) {
        console.log("Mobile breakpoint");
    } else if (tabletQuery.matches) {
        console.log("Tablet breakpoint");
    } else {
        console.log("Desktop breakpoint");
    }
}

// Execute the function initially to set the initial state
handleBreakpoints();

// Add listeners for changes in the media queries
mobileQuery.addListener(handleBreakpoints);
tabletQuery.addListener(handleBreakpoints);
```

This approach avoids continuous checking of the window width on every resize event, which can be resource-intensive. Instead, it listens for changes in the media queries and executes the appropriate code when the breakpoints are reached.