# Add browser max-width (media query) to javascript when hide header?

Tags: javascript, html, css, media-queries

Could use some help*

I want to control on which width my hide header (javascript) starts working lets say: at width 667px and downwards. It is for mobile viewing, but i don't want to use:

```
if( /Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry/i.test(navigator.userAgent) ) {
```

Because it  doesn't let me control some larger screen sizes like big tablets/phones.

I saw some media query scripts for javascript, but can't get it to work with the code you see below:

[--> Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7vtmbg1kx/11/)

```
// Hide header on scroll down //

var didScroll;
var lastScrollTop = 0;
var delta = 44;
var navbarHeight = $('header').outerHeight();

$(window).scroll(function(event){
didScroll = true;
});

setInterval(function() {
if (didScroll) {
    hasScrolled();
    didScroll = false;
}
}, 250);

function hasScrolled() {
var st = $(this).scrollTop();

// Make sure they scroll more than delta
if(Math.abs(lastScrollTop - st) <= delta)
    return;

// If they scrolled down and are past the navbar, add class .nav-up.
// This is necessary so you never see what is "behind" the navbar.
if (st > lastScrollTop && st > navbarHeight){
    // Scroll Down
    $('header').addClass('nav-up');
} else {
    // Scroll Up
    if(st + $(window).height() < $(document).height()) {
        $('header').removeClass('nav-up');
    }
}

lastScrollTop = st;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if your sole desire is to hide your header (your question is not exactly clear about that) when the viewport is smaller than n pixels you do not need any js for that. Use simple css media queries:

```
 @media screen and (max-width: 667px) {
     .your-header-class {
         display: none;
     }
 }
```

But if you want to go mobile first you should do:

```
/* general + mobile css */
.your-header-class {
     display: none;
}
/* tablet + desktop css only */
@media screen and (min-width: 667px) {
    .your-header-class {
        display: block;
    }
}
```

Otherwise check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31409882/how-to-most-efficiently-check-for-certain-breakpoints-upon-browser-re-size/31410149#31410149) I gave a couple of days ago.

I will repost the code with a couple of comments that might be of use for you:

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    // This will make sure your 'media query' will only run,
    // once your viewport has stopped changing in size
    clearTimeout(resizeTimer);
    resizeTimer = setTimeout(breakpointChange(), 400);
});

function breakpointChange() {
    // your window width
    width = window.innerWidth;

    // adapt the values (i.e. 667) here
    if (!mobile && width < 667) {        
        tablet = desktop = false;
        mobile = true;
        // this is mobile, so execute your js here
    }

    if (!tablet && width > 401 && width < 768) {
        mobile = desktop = false;
        tablet = true;
        console.log('is tablet');
    }

    if (!desktop && width > 769) {
        mobile = tablet = false;
        desktop = true;
        console.log('is desktop');
    }
}
// you'll need to call $(window).resize(); the first time your script loads
$(window).resize();
```

This allows you to control all media breakpoints - simply define your functions next to these two, and call them inside the appropriate conditional.

Comment: Thanks your answer guided me to the right answer: just move the class .nav-up to the media query that will show the mobile nav. I was thinking the wrong way, i thought the answer was to look for a JS solution.